# Backward definition of (La)TeX commands

Tags: macros, tex-core, syntax

*Again and again I see, that TeXnicians define commands and do several things with them in the reverse order, I would do this as amateur. See this example:*

In [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152858/9237) to [scrpage2: Three "marks" for headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152852/scrpage2-three-marks-for-headings) egreg defines a `\parttitle`, and even more he applies also a patch:

```
\apptocmd{\@part}{\parttitle{#2}}{}{}
\def\parttitle#1{\gdef\theparttitle{#1}}
\def\theparttitle{} % initialization
```

I would have done it in this way - first initialization, then real definition, and last patching:

```
\def\theparttitle{} % initialization
\def\parttitle#1{\gdef\theparttitle{#1}}
\apptocmd{\@part}{\parttitle{#2}}{}{}
```

A test shows, that this works, as well. So, my question is:

**What is the advantage of defining TeX commands backwards?**
*(At least from an amateur’s point of view …)*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's no technical difference, as long as content is available/declared when they are used. That's because TeX is a macro language where macros and their arguments are substituted for a replacement text - the latter is only evaluated when used (unless evaluated at definition, like with `\edef` or `\xdef`).

For example, looking at

```
\apptocmd{\@part}{\parttitle{#2}}{}{}
\def\parttitle#1{\gdef\theparttitle{#1}}
\def\theparttitle{} % initialization
```

Following the lines above:

1. `\apptocmd` adds stuff to `\@part`, so `\@part` should exist. At the time of *definition* (this insertion) though, `\parttitle` is not evaluated, and therefore does not have to exist.
2. `\def` just defines `\parttitle` and doesn't really care about whether anything inside its replacement text exists.
3. Some as (2).

From a TeXnician's point of view one might write the sequence this way by considering the source of the change as being `\@part` - the most important thing that requires a change; perhaps the last macro that actually sets the content. Subsequently, the change requires `\parttitle`, which is defined next. And `\parttitle` requires `\theparttitle`, which is defined next (as a safety/default). Viewing it differently makes just as much sense, by starting with the definition at the deepest level.

---

I think the main thing here is to understand that the TeX's macro-language uses

```
\<csname><argument text>{<replacement text>}
```

where `<replacement text>` is only considered/evaluated with a correct call to `\<csname>` (again, unless defined using some expansive technique (like `\edef` or `\xdef`).

Answer (score 16):

The real truth is that I first had

```
\apptocmd{\@part}{\gdef\theparttitle{#2}}{}{}
```

with no initialization. Then I realized it was better to have `\parttitle{#2}` and a macro for setting `\theparttitle` anywhere needed. Then I remembered that an initialization was necessary.

But this style is very common in Knuth's macros. For example, in `plain.tex`

```
225 \outer\def\newcount{\alloc@0\count\countdef\insc@unt}
226 \outer\def\newdimen{\alloc@1\dimen\dimendef\insc@unt}
    <other similar lines>
236 \outer\def\newlanguage{\alloc@9\language\chardef\@cclvi}
237 \def\alloc@#1#2#3#4#5{\global\advance\count1#1by\@ne
238   \ch@ck#1#4#2% make sure there's still room
239   \allocationnumber=\count1#1%
240   \global#3#5=\allocationnumber
241   \wlog{\string#5=\string#2\the\allocationnumber}}
```

Again

```
264 \outer\def\newif#1{\count@\escapechar \escapechar\m@ne
265   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
266    \def\@if#1{true}{\let#1=\iftrue}%
267   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
268    \def\@if#1{false}{\let#1=\iffalse}%
269   \@if#1{false}\escapechar\count@} % the condition starts out false
270 \def\@if#1#2{\csname\expandafter\if@\string#1#2\endcsname}
271 {\uccode`1=`i \uccode`2=`f \uppercase{\gdef\if@12{}}} % `if' is required
```

Presenting `\@if` before defining `\newif` would make it difficult to understand. It's always better to define auxiliary macros after the main one (if possible), so the role of each macro is clearer.

Last example

```
1017 \newbox\rootbox
1018 \def\root#1\of{\setbox\rootbox
1019   \hbox{$\m@th\scriptscriptstyle{#1}$}\mathpalette\r@@t}
1020 \def\r@@t#1#2{\setbox\z@\hbox{$\m@th#1\sqrt{#2}$}\dimen@\ht\z@
1021   \advance\dimen@-\dp\z@
1022   \mkern5mu\raise.6\dimen@\copy\rootbox \mkern-10mu\box\z@}
```

Allocating registers is best done before they are used, like declaring variables in programming languages. One might argue that in the code that started the discussion, `\theparttitle` is like a variable. However, TeX is based on macro expansion, so `\theparttitle` is actually a helper macro. If this had been written in LaTeX3, I'd have declared a token list variable beforehand.