# Headers and font in KOMA-script

Tags: koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

I am setting up the layout for my bachelor thesis using scrbook as basis for a self-made documentclass with twosided print. I want a header containing the current part number and name on the outer side (left on even pages, right on odd pages), the current chapter number and name on the center of the head and the same for section on the inner side. I found this example in the KOMA-Script documentation:

```
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\automark*[section]{}
```

It puts the chapter on the outer side on even pages and the section on the outer side on odd pages. Sadly, I was not able to modify this to fit my needs because I do not really understand the way KOMA-Script works here. If a part starts but there is still no chapter in it, the place for the chapter shall remain empty (same for chapter and section). Can anyone help?

Furthermore, I would like to change all fonts that KOMA-Script changes (e.g. toc, section, chapter...) back to the default computer modern as I do not like the font KOMA-Script uses here. Is there a better way than changing all the fonts manually like this:

```
\addtokomafont{section}{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont}
```

Comment: Your Bachelor report has section, chapters *and* parts? Ho many pages do you get at the end?

Comment: To the bonus question (usually, we have a one questioin per question limit): Try `emulatestandardclasses` as option to `documentclass`.

Comment: `\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}` changes all of those.

Comment: I expect about 80-100 pages, so I think it is useful to have parts.

Comment: emulatestandardclasses did not work, it mixed up with the header and produced a header containing the page number on the blank pages, while \addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily} worked quite well without side effects (as far as I can see). Thanks for that

Comment: Side effect? No. This is what `emulatestandardclasses` is supposed to do. The reason: It emulates the standard classes.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For the part entries in the page header I will modify my example from [scrpage2: Three “marks” for headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/253779/43317). Note that there must be no unstarred `\automark` command after the redefinition of `\partmark` because this would reset this definition.

To get serif font in the section titles you can change font element `disposition`

```
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\bfseries}
```

or you can use the undocumented option

```
headings=standardclasses
```

If also font elements like `descriptionlabel` should use the serif font you can set the undocumented option `egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles` which was a result of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/289853/43317) and needs KOMA version 3.20 or newer. **Update:** This undocumented option is deprecated. For KOMA-Script version 3.39 or newer there is now the *documented* class option `sfdefaults=false`.

```latex
\documentclass[
  sfdefaults=false,% needs version 3.39 or newer
  %headings=standardclasses
]{scrbook}
%\providecommand*\Ifstr{\ifstr}% needed up to and including KOMA-Script version 3.27, see https://komascript.de/faq_deprecatedif
%\providecommand*\Ifnumbered{\ifnumbered}% needed up to and including KOMA-Script version 3.27, see https://komascript.de/faq_deprecatedif
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% activates page style scrheadings automatically
\automark[section]{chapter}
\newmarks\currentpart

\renewcommand\partmark[1]{% after all unstarred \automark commands!
  \marks\currentpart{\Ifnumbered{part}{\partname~\thepart\autodot\enskip}{}#1}%
  \markboth{}{}%
  }
\newcommand\partinheadfoot{\firstmarks\currentpart}

\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\partinheadfoot}
\chead{\leftmark}
\ihead{\Ifstr{\leftmark}{\rightmark}{}{\rightmark}}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}

\renewcommand\partpagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{First Test}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\section{A Section}
\lipsum

\part{Second Test}
\chapter{Only a Chapter}
\lipsum

\part{Third Test}
\section{Only a Section}
\lipsum

\part{Fourth Test}
\lipsum
\begin{description}
\item[Testlabel] Text
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

If your part, chapter or section titles are to long for the header, you can use option `headings=optiontohead` or `headings=optiontoheadandtoc` to use a short title in head and the long (or an other) version in TOC. See the explanations for `\part[short version ]{heading` etc. in the KOMA-Script documentation section "3.16. Structuring of Documents".

Comment: Ha ha ha. Great sense of huour. :D

Comment: I have to upvote this tomorrow, i voted too much today.

Comment: @egreg @esdd I thought for once `egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles` this was a joke, good work!! :D

Comment: For koma  v3.39 or newer there is now the class option `sfdefaults=false` instead of `egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks for the hint.