# My Text has a different Font than Chapters/Sections

Tags: fonts, lmodern

I am pretty new to LaTeX. I used a template for my paper. The template uses the package "lmodern" as font. The text looks good as expected. However my Chapter/Section/Subsection Headers are not in "lmodern"...

e.g.
[image: Subsection vs. Text]

This is the interesting part of my preamble:

[image]

My Chapters dont have anything else but the actual text in it:
[image]

Comment: The class you load, `scrreport`, uses sans serif font for the title of chapters and sections

Comment: See eg. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/313156/43317.

Answer (score 2):

As Ivan brought up in the comments, the `scrreport` class (which is the Koma-Script version of `report`) sets all headings to be sans-serif by default.

The manual says that you can change this with

```
\addtokomafont{part}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\addtokomafont{partnumber}{\normalfont\bfseries}
```

But there’s also a class option for it.

```
\documentclass[egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles]{scrreport}
```

The name is a TeX.SX inside joke.