# Wrong font in section/subsection

Tags: koma-script, fontspec

Im using fontspec to have Arial in my scrartcl -document. For some reason this Arial is not applied to sectiontitle/subsectiontitle. Compiling with Xelatex

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Font %%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

%%%%%%%%%%% header %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[headsepline=0.75pt]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\renewcommand*{\headfont}{\normalfont}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\automark[section]{section}
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{Section 1}
11111111111111111111111
\subsection{Subsection 1}
11111111111111111111111
\subsubsection{Subsubsection 1}
11111111111111111111111
\end{document}
```

Comment: See eg. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/313156/43317.

Comment: thanks, perfect